# Regular Expression To Match HTML Comment Contents

Tags: php, regex

For example, if I have this code:

```
<!--start-here-->
<div>My Cool Content!!!</div>
<h1>Headerrr</h1>
<!--end-here-->
<div>Other Content</div>
```

How can I use a regular expression to just get the content between <--start-here--> and <--end-here-->?

So my output would be:

```
<div>My Cool Content!!!</div>
<h1>Headerrr</h1>
```

Comment: Are those tags repeating or it's just one block ?

Comment: The start and end tags only appear once

Comment: /<!--start-here-->(.*?)<!--end-here--->/ims

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex

```
$str = '<!--start-here-->
        <div>My Cool Content!!!</div>
        <h1>Headerrr</h1>
        <!--end-here-->
        <div>Other Content</div>';

$return = explode('<!--start-here-->', $str);
$return = explode('<!--end-here-->', $return[1]);
$return = $return[0];
```

or with regex

```
$str = preg_match('/<!--start-here-->[\s\S]*<!--end-here-->/', $str, $return);
$return = $return[0];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
/<!--start-here-->(.*?)<!--end-here--->/ims
```

this should work

Comment: if you need info about RegEx, ask here, now

Comment: i dont see why not; there are no characters that need to be escaped ... if modifications are needed just use this one: /[<][!][-][-]start[-]here[-][-][>](.*?)[<][!][-][-]end[-]here[-][-][-][>]/ims

Comment: I thought the "." matches anything *except* a newline? If so, should it not say (.\n*?) ...? To be fair though, I'm not sure how the dot character is handled in php.

Comment: no no, the . matches everything; the m after /i is for multyline

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
<!--start-here-->(.|\n)*<!--end-here-->
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick: `/<!--start-here-->.*<!--end-here-->/m`.
Use it like this: `/<!--start-here-->.*<!--end-here-->/m.exec(htmlCode)`